# how to alter program preferences to run in background rather than foreground

Tags: background-process

I have been using commands like

`gedit some_script.pl &` for many years.

However, I would like to force the program to automatically run in the background, so that I would get the command line back, and I don't type `&`.

How can I alter some setting somewhere so that when I type

`gedit somescript.pl`

will instead get the behavior of

`gedit somescript.pl &`?

Comment: @muru, somewhat, but the answer given by terdon down below is significantly better than the answer on that link

Comment: My answer is almost identical to the other one. That's why I voted to close. We even gave the function the same (admittedly pretty obvious) name. The only extra bit mine has is how to keep the same command name, but that's not a very significant change. Am I missing something?

Comment: @terdon .bashrc was missing, I wouldn't have gotten that from the answer on that webpage.  Your answer below is much better.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I'll edit that into the other one then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function. Add this to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent if you're not using bash):

```
geditbg(){
    gedit "$@" &
}
```

Then, open a new terminal (or just run `. ~/.bashrc`) and you can now run `geditbg somescript.pl` and it will open in the background.

If you don't want to change the command name, you can do (change `/usr/bin/gedit` to whatever you get when you run `which gedit` on your system):

```
gedit(){
    /usr/bin/gedit "$@" &
}
```